# Strange behavior when dragging items on the second drag react-beautiful-dnd

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, react-beautiful-dnd

For some reason every second drag is not performing very well when using the react-beautiful-dnd package (see image)

[image]

my onDragEnd function is looking like this:

```
  const onDragEnd = result => { 
    if (!result.destination) {
      return;
    }

    if (
      result.destination.droppableId === result.source.droppableId &&
      result.destination.index === result.source.index
    ) {
       return;
    }

    const draggedItem = list[result.source.index];
    list.splice(result.source.index, 1);
    list.splice(result.destination.index, 0, draggedItem);

    /** Firebase update */
    dbCon.once('value', function(snapshot) {
       snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
         list.map((listChild, index) => {
           if (listChild.props.draggableId === child.key) {
             child.ref.update({ position: index });
           }
         });
       });
     });

    setList(getNodes);
  };
```

Having getNodes that is returning child components

Not sure what the responsible is for this behaviour.. any ideas?

Comment: can you provide a mcve (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example) https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ?

Comment: Not clear what the strange behavior is, you didnt really say.

Comment: @Simran I think the problem here is that on the second drag animation it kind of offcenters the other listitem. I struggle with the same problem.

Comment: @2hTu2 perhaps the problem is that i take the draggedItem out of the array and after removing the item placing the draggedItem back to the array.. So maybe somekind of an index issue?

Comment: @alexandereardon

Comment: Did you solve this issue ? I am the similar issue. Can you have a look at this https://github.com/softmantk/react-dnd-example.git     sometimes, the drag will not work. And usually it is 2nd drag

Comment: @NIKHILCM actually i did! I found this article what is explaining the problem and give you some handles to fix this:
https://medium.com/@eamonngiblin/dynamically-update-positions-during-drag-using-react-beautiful-dnd-4a986d704c2e 
"your array is being modified in two places (from dnd and from your setState in onDrag), getting re-rendered on the state change despite already being in a Drag action and these are all creating some pretty wonky side effects."

Comment: thank @RonaldZwiers. But I am still not getting the solution.It will be very helpful if you can you have a look at my code. https://codesandbox.io/embed/github/softmantk/react-dnd-example/tree/master/  

If I drag item 1 (take out the garbage) and draging the 2nd item (watch movie) the issue will arise. 

The onDragEnd logic is very simple but having this weired issue.

Comment: @RonaldZwiers, Downgrading to v10 solved the issue for me.

Comment: try upgrading to `11.0.0-beta.2`

Answer (score 0):

I had this similar issue when I used react-beautiful-dnd version  11.0.0-beta.

`Downgrading to 10.1.1 fixed the problem.`

You can find the similar issue with 11.0.0-beta where isDragDisabled not working  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55556640/getting-error-find-drag-handle-element-inside-of-draggable-when-adding-isdragd/55556988#55556988)

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that `11.0` is still in `beta`! It is not recommended for production yet. If you face any issues, please use the stable `10.x` release.

We appreciate details on any issues you are facing with `11.0` so we can address them. [Submit an issue](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/issues)