# Getting Error : find drag handle element inside of Draggable when adding isDragDisabled flag in draggable

Tags: reactjs, react-beautiful-dnd

When I set  isDragDisabled to  true (hard coded) I am getting an error like this

```
index.js:1446 raw Error: Invariant failed: 
      Cannot find drag handle element inside of Draggable.
      Please be sure to apply the {...provided.dragHandleProps} to your Draggable
```

My draggable component is

```
class Task extends Component {
    render() {
        console.log("taskID: ", this.props.task.id, this.props.task.id === 1)
        return (
            <Draggable
                draggableId={this.props.task.id}
                index={this.props.index}
                isDragDisabled={true}
            >
                {
                    (provided, snapshot) => {
                        // console.log("SN:DRAGBLE:TASK: ", snapshot)
                        return <Container
                            {...provided.draggableProps}
                            {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                            ref={provided.innerRef}
                            isDragging={snapshot.isDragging}
                        >

                            {`
                        ${this.props.task.id} :
                        ${this.props.task.content}
                        `}
                        </Container>
                    }
                }
            </Draggable>
        );
    }
}
```

and droppable is :

```
class Column extends Component {

    render() {

        return (
            <Container>
                <Title>{`${this.props.column.title}: ${this.props.column.id}`}</Title>
                <Droppable droppableId={this.props.column.id}>
                    {
                        (provided, snapshot) => {
                            // console.log("SN:DRPABLE:CLMN: ", snapshot)
                            return <TaskList
                                ref={provided.innerRef}
                                {...provided.droppableProps}
                                isDragging={snapshot.isDraggingOver}
                            >
                                {
                                    this.props.tasks.map((task, index) => <Task key={index} task={task} index={index}/>)
                                }
                                {provided.placeholder}
                            </TaskList>
                        }
                    }


                </Droppable>

            </Container>
        );
    }
}
```

You can find the code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/embed/github/softmantk/react-dnd-example/tree/test-drag-disable/

if  `isDragDisabled` prop  is removed from the file components/task.js, it will run fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the version of react-beautiful-dnd from 11.0.0-beta to 10.1.1 will fix this problem.

I created a github issue for this: https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/issues/1224

Comment: Thanks! It fixed my issue. 

It also fixed another issue like this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55504775/strange-behavior-when-dragging-items-on-the-second-drag-react-beautiful-dnd/55557731#55557731

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in `11.0.0-beta.2`. Upgrading to that version will fix your issue